# Loading modules from a certain folder

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, module, loading

I'm working with modules and each of it will be compiled (deployed) in a common folder in a webproject. In the main class I defined an array of module paths which I need for loading all these defined modules.

How can I make that more dynamically, for instance, I want to say, load all modules in a certain folder an its subfolders without to know each module by name.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do anything in a Flex/AS3 related browser based app to get information about folders on the server.

You're going to have to write a server side service to get the information.  Any technology should work, such as .NET, ColdFusion, PHP, Java, or whatever.  Then just call the service, and it should send you back the information you need.  In ColdFusion, you'd use the [cfdirectory](http://www.cfquickdocs.com/cf8/?getDoc=cfdirectory) tag.